# The C compiler "/usr/bin/clang" is not able to compile a simple test program

Tags: ide, cmake, clang

Why does my C compiler (Clang) fail to compile a simple test program when opening a CMake project in CLion?

I'm trying to setup CLion to run with CMake, Ninja, Clang and Clang++.
To test it I tried opening a new project, the Clang source.
When opening a new project I selected ~/src/llvm-project/clang/

Clion then opens the project and proceeds to immediately give me the following debug output:

> /snap/clion/85/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/usr/bin/ninja -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang++ -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /home/kim/src/llvm-project/clang
>   -- The C compiler identification is Clang 6.0.0
>   -- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 6.0.0
>   -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/clang
>   -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/clang -- broken
>   CMake Error at /snap/clion/85/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
>     The C compiler
>
> "/usr/bin/clang"
>
> is not able to compile a simple test program.
>
> It fails with the following output:
>
> Change Dir: /home/kim/src/llvm-project/clang/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/ninja cmTC_a3bcb/fast && ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja': No such file or directory
>
> CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
>   Call Stack (most recent call first):
>     CMakeLists.txt:10 (project)
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
>   See also "/home/kim/src/llvm-project/clang/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
>   See also "/home/kim/src/llvm-project/clang/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

CMakeOutput.log contains:

> The system is: Linux - 5.0.0-29-generic - x86_64
>   Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded.
>   Compiler: /usr/bin/clang 
>   Build flags: 
>   Id flags:
>
> The output was:
>   0
>
> Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "a.out"
>
> The C compiler identification is Clang, found in "/home/kim/src/llvm-project/clang/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/3.15.3/CompilerIdC/a.out"
>
> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
>   Compiler: /usr/bin/clang++ 
>   Build flags: 
>   Id flags:
>
> The output was:
>   0
>
> Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "a.out"
>
> The CXX compiler identification is Clang, found in "/home/kim/src/llvm-project/clang/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/3.15.3/CompilerIdCXX/a.out"

The CMakeError.log contains:

> Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
>   Change Dir: /home/kim/src/llvm-project/clang/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/ninja cmTC_a3bcb/fast && ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also asked JetBrains for help and apparently CLion doesn't yet support Ninja CMake generator.
I will simply have to use make instead of Ninja for now.
Work is ongoing to support Ninja as well.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/2306298